# how to add QuickBase a CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, sdk, quickbase

I'm looking for how to integrate the QuickBase API in a website developed with the CodeIgniter framework
I esayer add the api as a library

```
$this->load->library('quickbase', 'login','password', true, 'table');
```

and when I do I call displays error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1 for QuickBase::__construct(), called in /var/www/vhosts/************/httpdocs/system/core/Loader.php on line 1099 and defined

Filename: libraries/quickbase.php

Line Number: 43

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 2 for QuickBase::__construct(), called in /var/www/vhosts/**************/httpdocs/system/core/Loader.php on line 1099 and defined

Filename: libraries/quickbase.php

Line Number: 43

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: un

Filename: libraries/quickbase.php

Line Number: 45

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: pw

Filename: libraries/quickbase.php

Line Number: 49
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because the Quickbase API file(s) does not have the same calling format as a CodeIgniter library needs to work with the `load->library` syntax. You will need to read up on the [Creating Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) section of the manual and then create your own CodeIgniter compatible Quickbase library that includes the file(s) for the Quickbase API.